# Which sensor should be used to measure jump height on the beach?

Tags: sensor

For a jump height measuring device to have feedback of what training works.

Comment: Camera + some image processing.

Comment: A stick and a ruler.

Comment: Most places use these things: https://www.roguefitness.com/vertec-jump-measuring-device You could probably add electronics to it if you were determined enough...

Comment: Needs more context for the operating conditions.

Comment: Omg I first tried asking this question on Arduino.stackexchange.com and it got closed because the "closer" saidit wasn't about Arduino even tough I planned on making it using Arduino. Now it get's closed here. Could the people closing and voting down give some feeback on how to ask this question properly? What to do to reopen? I did describe the problem i want to solve: measuring jump height on the beach to have feedback which types of training give best results.

Comment: Which library would you use for image processing? How much compute power does it require?

Comment: Do you see the price on that thing? roguefitness.com/vertec-jump-measuring-device?
700$ for an extendable stick with a few other sticks

Comment: how precise does it need to be? ... how about something with multiple horizontal laser beams ... the jump height would be detected by which beams were interrupted during the jump .... you may want to drop the `on the beach` from your question ... right now it is similar to `I want to build a blue race car`

Comment: @X10D You could make one yourself pretty easily for much cheaper. Add some switches to know which ones move, hook it to an Arduino and you're all set.

Comment: @jsotola the reason I added "on the beach" is because jumping on sand is a bit different than on hard surfaces.

Comment: @RonBeyer what type of switches?

Comment: @X10D jumping may be different on sand, but you are talking about measuring height, not about jumping difficulty ... jump height is the vertical distance between two points, no matter where the jump occurs

Answer (score 1):

I would use a 3-Axis MEMS accelerometer and a precision timer.  The accelerometer only needs to be able to tell the difference between free-fall and not free-fall. The "precision timer" is something you basically get for free as part of the microcontroller to which the accelerometer is interfaced.

If you assume that the person wearing it jumps from a level plane and lands in the same plane, then you can calculate the height from the duration of free fall.

---

<strike>P.S.: If you want to sell it to people who own cell phones, then there's no need for any hardware at all. It's all already built-in to the phone.</strike>

@Eugene Sh said,

> I doubt this will give any good accuracy. Especially the cellphone based...

OK, I am retracting the cellphone suggestion. When the idea first popped into my head, I pictured a dedicated microcontroller with some means to sample accelerometers at a few hundred Hz or better.

I have barely gone any deeper into cellphone app development than "Hello World." I have no idea how many layers of "location services" would come between a user-mode app and the hardware or, of the frequency response of a typical cell-phone accelerometer or, of what sample rates the hardware would be capable.

Comment: I doubt this will give any good accuracy. Especially the cellphone based. Just gut feeling, quantifying it will take some research though.

Comment: Cellphone accelerometers are actually highly precise, if you account the drift using the gyroscope, you can get the accuracy down to a few cm, at worst.

Comment: well theoretically drift isn't a problem since you can reset it after every jump?

Answer (score 1):

1. Put a measuring stick in the sand and have the person jump next to it.
2. Record a video of the jump with a camera
3. Play the video back slowly until you see the highest point.
4. Look at the measuring stick for your answer.

Apparently there is already a phone app that can do this measurement.
https://www.thehoopsgeek.com/measurement-app/

I also agree with Solomon Slow's answer regarding the use of an Accelerometer + MCU.  But with the exception that the accelerometer must have sufficient sample rate and bandwidth to capture the jump.

To figure out the accelerometer characteristcs you need to consider the following.

- **Sample rate:** If we take an average human jump to be about 16 inches.  Then the total time to fall from the apex of the jump to the ground is about 300ms.  To make an accurate measurement you also would want to make many samples during the 300ms fall (or rise) time.  A sample rate of 5ms (200Hz) would give you 60 samples, which is probably adequate.
- **Bandwidth:**  As a first guess we might say that the freefall time looks like a parabola which approximates one quarter of a sine wave having a period of 1.2s (0.83Hz).  But of course the person might extend their body during the jump so that changes the signal shape and increases the bandwidth.  Its hard to say exactly what that would be without an actual measurement, but assuming it was on the order of 10Hz might be safe.  We would want the accelerometer bandwidth to be significantly higher than the signal bandwidth to get a good reading (say 10X).  Something on the order of 100Hz or more would brobably be sufficient.
- **Measurement range:**  Trying to make an estimate of how fast someone might extend their body indicates that something with a range of at least ±4G is advisable.

Comment: How to calculate what the sufficient sample rate and bandwidth is needed?

Comment: I added some info on the accelerometer characteristics in the answer.